# Marror and Chazeres on the seder plate

Tags: marror-bitter-herbs, passover, minhag

The arrangement of the Seder plate according to the Arizal includes one space for "Marror" and another for "Chazeres" (the latter intended for use in Koreich). Does this reflect a tradition to use lettuce only for Koreich, but some other species for the primary Marror? The names are especially jarring for those who use horseradish exclusively.

Comment: Aren't they just as jarring for those who use romaine lettuce exclusively? Or endives exclusively?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Shaar Hakollel ([48:11](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=16002&pgnum=139)) says that indeed some people, because of this difference in terminology, do use different species for each one. Their rationale, he says, is that they're not sure which are the five species listed in the Mishnah (Pesachim 39a), so they prefer to use an actual bitter vegetable (horseradish, I guess) for maror, and then lettuce for chazeres.

However, he says that this practice is incorrect: lettuce should preferably be used for both. (Present-day Chabad custom is to compromise and use lettuce *and* horseradish for both.) The reason for calling the stuff for koreich "chazeres," he says, is to make it clear that it needn't be the actual species called "maror" (wormwood).

In his commentary on the Haggadah, the Lubavitcher Rebbe zt"l [cites](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=10502&pgnum=9) this, but argues that if that's the reason, then the term "chazeres" should have been used for both items on the Seder plate. So he suggests that the reason for the different terms, maror vs. chazeres, is simply that each of them reflects different Kabbalistic concepts: one related to the maror that's eaten alone, the other to koreich - but not necessarily that they are meant to be different species.

Comment: If it's the same species, then why have two separate spots?

Answer (score 1):

The other vegetable is probably the one used for *karpas*, if I understand the *Ramba"m* in *Hilchos chametz umatza* 8:1,2 correctly. It is clear from the *g'mara* on which these *halachos* are based (*P'sachim* 114b) and *Tosafos* (*ad loc.*) that *chazeres* (i.e. some type of lettuce) is the assumed species of *maror* and a suitable species of *karpas* as well.

Comment: How does that explain why one is called "maror" and the other "chazeres"?

Comment: The Tosafos I referenced explains that the _mishna_ used that term specifically to indicate that even if the only vegetable available was one suitable for _maror_ one would still dip twice in order to inspire the children's questions.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand how that answers the question. They should either both be "marror" or both "chazeres."

Comment: The advantage could be that while one is named after the _mitzva_ done with the object, i.e. _maror_, the other simply names the material to be placed there (like _betza_) because it is specifically _not_ associated with a _mitzva_.

Comment: So what you're saying, basically, is that "Maror" refers to the mitzvah while "Chazeres" refers to the item. That theory could be true even without the whole karpas business.

Comment: Yes. But the point of having the chazeres as a separate entity on the plate is for use as karpas, even if it is the same species as the marror, and technically can be put together in one spot. People would use the chazeres for karpas and then again for marror. Perhaps the reason why the other position is labeled marror is because it is pointed to (or lifted) when we say "marror zu...".
The same is implied in Abarbanel's haggada.